# How to pass value to a variable in an inherited class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a class called `TimeLineViewController` which is inherited from `MyViewController`. I need to pass a value to a variable from `MyViewController` to `TimeLineViewController`. How can i do it ?

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : TimeLineViewController {
.....
}
```

In `TimeLineViewController.h` i have a `String *str` assigned. From `MyViewController.m` i need to pass a value to the  `String *str` variable in the `TimeLineViewController` class. How can i do this.

I tried the following from `MyViewController.m` but none worked.

```
[super str]=@"hi";
```

Comment: Whats wrong with [self setStr:@"hi"]?

Answer (score 1):

The point of inheritance is using existing functionality and extending it for specific needs by the sub class(es)

So... If your `TimeLineViewController` inherits from `MyViewController` there is no need to declare the member again in `TimeLineViewController` and you can just use it with since it was already declared for `MyViewController`:

```
self.str = @"hi";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is a property inside the class `TimeLineViewController` you can access it via inheritance in `MyViewController`. So if you change it in `MyViewController` it changes also for the father.

Remember:

```
   A    

   |

   B
```

if in `A` you have a property `c` then you can do `B.c`.

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the apple's doc,

> The instance variable is accessible within the class that declares it
>   and within classes that inherit it. All instance variables without an
>   explicit scope directive have @protected scope.

So you can just use as

```
super.str = @"hi";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have setter or property in TimeLineViewController.

Then you can use

```
    [self setStr:@""];
```

or

```
    self.str = @"";
```